# Balancing Group In Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, regex

Does regular expression in Objc support balancing group? if not, Is there any other solution to fix it?

I find the pattern syntax currently supported is that specified by ICU in [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/) And [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) tells nothing about balancing group.

A simple test for balancing group,

```
(?'group'1)2(?'-group'3)(?(group)?!)
```

I test it both in Xcode search field and using NSRegularExpression.

Here are the code and error:

```
NSError* error;
re = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?'group'1)2(?'-group'3)(?(group)?!)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSLog(error);
```

Error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2048 "The value “(?'group'1)2(?'-group'3)(?(group)?!)” is invalid." UserInfo=0x1003b85b0 {NSInvalidValue=(?'group'1)2(?'-group'3)(?(group)?!)}
```

Comment: Balancing groups are unique to .NET's regex flavor.

Comment: If it's not there, it means that it's simply not supported.